# Does Dovecot no longer work under xInetd?

Tags: centos, dovecot, xinetd

I've been trying to get Dovecot to work under CentOS 7 with xinetd and I get errors such as:

Error: net_connect_unix(anvil) failed: No such file or directory
Fatal: Couldn't connect to anvil

and the connection closed.

Research online seems to indicate that Dovecot may no longer support xinetd?

http://www.dovecot.org/list/dovecot/2012-July/084725.html

There is no info about "xinetd" on the Dovecot Wiki.

Is anybody running Dovecot under xinetd?   Or is it a lost cause?

Comment: Why aren't you using the systemd socket activation that it shipped with?

Comment: I was using it as a service but I have other needs.

Comment: xinetd is pretty much obsolete. Basically you `yum install dovecot` and go do something else.

Comment: No, that doesn't give me the granular level of control I want over what hosts can access which services.   I want to be able to ban certain IPs from accessing smtp.  I want to make better use of memory resources and only run daemons when they're needed.

Comment: You should completely rewrite your question to explain what you really want to do, rather than [getting stuck on a particular solution](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/189912).

Comment: The question still stands.  I need to know if dovecot no longer supports xinetd.  If I get that answer, I know what I need to do.